# Ionic wkwebview random white screen

Tags: ionic-framework, wkwebview

I'm using ionic version 1.2.4 with wkwebview*

White screen will occur randomly in the app. The app is very huge and I couldn't replicate the white screen issue using the same steps.

Is this cause by memory issue when navigating to another view?

If yes how can I increase the memory exponentially in my code?

*https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost

It doesn't happen in a iOS simulator and only occurs in physical devices. Is the memory for the iOS simulator infinite? which explains why it doesnt hit this memory issue?

**Error logs:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/97yfy0yieq2yccu/errorLogWhiteScreen20170214?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1nqyizp932x0t5/errorLogWhiteScreen20170214_2?dl=0

Comment: I think difficult to help without seeing the app itself.
I saw a white screen when making the transition between being routed to different parents. I have had a problem when I changed the standard animation transition between pages

Comment: @grinmax I couldn't share the app since I've signed the NDA. But is this a known issue for ionic app (version 1.2.4)? Do you have the link to proof that it's a known issue? I couldn't find it for version 1 but this is for ionic version2 https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8677

Comment: I fixed the problem by using this solution (android device version 4.2.1 ) https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html

Answer (score 0):

bit late to the party but if it happens only on iOS, we fixed it with:

```
//the following hack fixes the random white screen when tapping quickly
if (window.device) {
    if (window.device.platform === PARAMETERS.IOS) {
        console.log('iOS hack done.');
        $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
        $ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

This is Ionic 1.3